# If $u+\iota v$ is analytic function, then $dv$ is equal to?

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

If $u+\iota v$ is analytic function, then $dv$ is equal to:

My attempt: $dv=v_xdx+v_ydy$ and since $u+\iota v$ is analytics, C-R eqns are satisfies and we have $u_x=v_y$ and $u_y=-v_x$. So, $dv=-u_ydx+u_xdy$. But the solution key says the answer is:

> $dv=-u_ydx-u_xdy$

What am I doing wrong here? Am I missing something important? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your answer is correct.

Comment: Thank you, I just wanted to verify since the ans key is different.